# JPA method findAll() from repository is null

Tags: spring, jpa, crud

I implemented a repository, an entity and a POJO where I want to call the findAll() method from the repository, but it returns null pointer exception, even though I have the database populated. The problem is that the repo is null, not the list after executing the select.
Can anyone help me?

This is my repo:

```
 @Repository
 public interface UpcomingMatchesFactsRepository  extends 
 CrudRepository<UpcomingMatchesFacts, Integer> {

    public boolean existsByFirstPlayerName(String firstPlayerName);

    @Query(value = "" +
            "Select u " +
            "from UpcomingMatchesFacts u " +
            "order by abs(formula) desc ")
    List<UpcomingMatchesFacts> getHighestFormulaMatches();

    List<UpcomingMatchesFacts> findAll();
}
```

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "upcomingmatchesfacts")
public class UpcomingMatchesFacts {

    public UpcomingMatchesFacts(String firstPlayerName, String secondPlayerName, int matchesWonFirstPlayer,
                                int matchesWonSecondPlayer, int currentRankFirstPlayer, int currentRankSecondPlayer,
                                int ageFirstPlayer, int ageSecondPlayer, double formula) {
        this.firstPlayerName = firstPlayerName;
        this.secondPlayerName = secondPlayerName;
        this.matchesWonFirstPlayer = matchesWonFirstPlayer;
        this.matchesWonSecondPlayer = matchesWonSecondPlayer;
        this.currentRankFirstPlayer = currentRankFirstPlayer;
        this.currentRankSecondPlayer = currentRankSecondPlayer;
        this.ageFirstPlayer = ageFirstPlayer;
        this.ageSecondPlayer = ageSecondPlayer;
        this.formula = formula;
    }
```

And this is the class where I want to use the method:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ChooseBestMatches {

    @Autowired
    private UpcomingMatchesFactsRepository upcomingMatchesFactsRepository;


    public void addBestMatchesToDatabase() {
        List<UpcomingMatchesFacts> upcomingMatchesFacts = Lists.newArrayList(upcomingMatchesFactsRepository.findAll());

                //upcomingMatchesFactsRepository.getHighestFormulaMatches().subList(0, 9);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject spring bean into other class, it must be a spring bean too. Use @Service annotation on ChooseBestMatches class.

Advice: @EnableJpaRepositories should be on a Configuation class, not on a service.
Entities must have noarg constructor.

Comment: I made the changes, but I get the same error :(

Comment: can you please copy the stack trace into pastebin and link it here?